# Always ask me to re-upload files during sync Aptana

Tags: ftp, aptana, synchronization, sftp, aptana3

I've a project hosted remotely and sync by Aptana, but Aptana Sync always ask me to re-upload almost all files even those files having no change at all by his file difference detector except the file's modified date. It's so annoying that when I download files from the remote ftp, the modified date of the files in the local folders changes, the next time I sync local and remote folders I need to re-upload all files again since the date changed.

Is there any method to get rid of this issue?

There is no such problem in netbean.
Thanks.